# how to show absolute path image in html [ yii2 ]

Tags: html, css, yii2

I can refrence a pic like this

But i dont want to save user data images in the website path,so i try to locate test.jpg in

```
/home/www/userdata/username/test.jpg
```

but just cant ref it's abs path ,when showing on html the pic not displayed,it's like this:

```
<img src="/home/www/userdata/username/test.jpg"/>
```

i muset point out that ,i dont want store user datas inside webroot,neither want i store it in database.

In this case,webroot and userdata  are at same dir : /home/www/(www serves as an username)

Do i need wirte and image server so i can ref image by http?

Any suggest is appretiated~

Answer (score 0):

where is your HTML Page is located ?

If  located in www then you can use like following :

```
<img src="userdata/username/test.jpg"/>
```

Otherwise remove "/" before home:

```
<img src="home/www/userdata/username/test.jpg"/>
```

Comment: /home/www is the common father dir of usrdata and yiiwebroot

Comment: Then try this : <img src="home/www/userdata/username/test.jpg"/>

Comment: remvove the  "/" before the "home"